# tizen native button with transparent color possible?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I want to set an image on a button and set its background color to be transparent.
We can show button with default color and set an icon on it, but when I set the colors alpha value to zero or less everything turns to be transparent. I need to show the image on the button at least.

> So how do I set transparent background with code?

other solutions all with EDC editor or EDC code, that is not supported on new Tizen 5.5.

code:

```
Evas_Object *box = elm_box_add(ad->win);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(box, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
elm_object_content_set(ad->conform,box);
evas_object_show(box);

ad->button = elm_button_add(ad->conform);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(ad->button,0.0,1.0);
evas_object_size_hint_align_set(ad->button,-1.0,1.0);
elm_object_text_set(ad->button,"");
evas_object_color_set(ad->button, 255, 100, 100, 250); //any transparency?
evas_object_show(ad->button);
elm_box_pack_end(box,ad->button);

Evas_Object *ic;
ic = elm_icon_add(ad->button);
elm_image_file_set(ic,ICON_DIR"/ok.png",NULL);
elm_object_part_content_set(ad->button,"icon",ic);
evas_object_show(ic);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to change only the button background color.

If you use the click event with elm_image, I think you can create what you want.

(https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/ui-components/wearable-ui-components/image)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I have discovered that previously. I do not want to use an image. I figured this applies to other widget too. But background is an issue now. Custom background is required to give it a feel of a button.